# Installing Indigo after Kinetic?

Tags: kinect, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For reasons detailed here, I have been using Kinetic but need to install Indigo:
http://answers.ros.org/question/240650/im-doing-a-turtlebot-based-project-should-i-just-install-indigo/

As is clear there, I am a total noob to ROS. Is there a protocol for installing a new (old) distribution of ROS once you already have one? I've googled it and didn't find anything explicit. For instance, once I run roscore, which version will run? If I just install indigo and then source the bash will that become the default? Or are there collisions/conflicts I'll need to resolve such that it might be best just to uninstall Kinetic Kame?

I'm in Ubuntu 16.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240718/installing-indigo-after-kinetic?/) by [neuronet](https://answers.ros.org/users/27484/neuronet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2016-07-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can not install indigo on Ubuntu 16.04. I had a similar problem in which I had to downgrade to indigo from kinetic. However, I found out that ROS Indigo ONLY supports Saucy (13.10) and Trusty (14.04) for Debian packages. . So I got it from here.

> http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/

I had Ubuntu 16.04 with dual boot with Windows 10. As there was no other way to downgrade Ubuntu 16.04 to 14.04, I had to erase ubuntu 16.04 and install a fresh Ubuntu 14.04.
After that I installed Indigo>
And everything was working well :)

So to answer your question, you have to install Ubuntu 14.04 to get indigo!
Have fun :)

---

Originally posted by [submetu](https://answers.ros.org/users/27639/submetu/) with karma: 46 on 2016-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [neuronet](https://answers.ros.org/users/27484/neuronet/) on 2016-07-31**:
Thanks for the info. That's too bad. I really like Ubuntu 16...might just wait a year and do mindstorms :) ...[update--just installed Ubuntu 14. It is amazing the little things in 16 that made it a lot better, from how they handle software updates, customizability, power management, etc..sigh]